# How to see Android OS System log file?

Tags: adb, logging

After leaving my Samsung Galaxy A-30 phone (with Android 9) for a few hours unbelievably I understood all of my internal storage is cleaned! I don't remember that I have installed any suspicious app but I just attached a USB flash to my phone for some data transferring last day.

Now I just want to know what happened to my phone's internal storage data, is there any system log file for Android 9? How can I find if an app with storage permission has done this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! For a starter, please take a look at our [logging tag wiki](/tags/logging/info) and follow up to [How can I view and examine the Android log?](/q/14430/16575).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find it with `adb logcat`